# Is it possible to change the "Background Image Location" column of the list to a "Choice" column?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list

We would like users to be able to simply select from a menu of background image options rather than having to type or copy the url into text box.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution by using [Asset picker](https://azzu-sheikh.blogspot.com/2015/05/add-asset-pickerbrowse-and-select-file.html)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// With the below line we will be dynamically adding the Browse control next to the textbox where we need to place this. 

//Replace "controlid" with your actual id of the textbox.

$("textarea#controlid").closest('td').append("<div id='btnbrowsectrl' style='display:none'><input onclick='GetFileURL()' type='button' value='Browse File' /><span>Browse File location if exists on same site</span></div>");

 //The below snippet to acheive the browse functionality
//Create a object which will be used for the Asset. I have used the object name as 'assetPickerObj'
    with(new AssetPickerConfig('assetPickerObj'))
    {{
         DefaultAssetImageLocation='';
         //CurrentWebBaseUrl will be the url of the site or site collection.
         CurrentWebBaseUrl='https://siteurl.com';
         OverrideDialogFeatures='';
         OverrideDialogTitle='';
         OverrideDialogDesc='';
         OverrideDialogImageUrl='';
         //AssetUrlClientID is the id of the control in which the path of the selected file will be saved.
         AssetUrlClientID='controlid';
         AssetTextClientID='';                                                             
         UseImageAssetPicker=false; //make this false to show Documents instead
         DefaultToLastUsedLocation=true;
         DisplayLookInSection=true;                                                            
         ReturnCallback = null;}}
});

function GetFileURL(){
    //Following is the function which launch the AssetPortalBrowser.aspx automatically.
    APD_LaunchAssetPickerUseConfigCurrentUrl('assetPickerObj');

//the above line will just give you the relative url to the textbox.
//set absolute url in textbox if required then use the below lines
var newabsoluteurl= window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host+$("#controlid ").val().replace(/\s+/g,"%20");
$("#controlid").val(newabsoluteurl);

return false;

}
```